# activate htaccess only on specific URI

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite, http-basic-authentication

I have an apache webserver running on an ubuntu system.
To avoid access for unauthorized users, I have an active `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "own area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
require user username
```

This `.htacces`  works fine by accessing all files insight the document root, like the `index.php`. In this case, user authentication is required.
But now I'm looking for an way to disable this user authentication, if an specific uri was called, like: `index.php?s=abc` In this case and only in this case the application should be available without authentication.

Is there a way to realize that?
I'm not sure, how to start searching the web for that specific question?

Is the `RewriteEngine` the key?

The server vhost config has an active rewrite rule with the following configuration:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
  RewriteRule ^/([\w]+)$ /index.php?s=$1   [L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to .htaccess, in addition to the authentication configuration:

```
# Set environment variable "allow" only for URL /index.php?s=abc
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=abc$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [E=allow]

# Allow access when allow is set
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow

# Grant access by Allow OR user authentication
Satisfy any
```

Comment: That looks great and I see, that I'm far away from understanding the Apache rewrite-world. Unfortunately, this example doesn't work out of the box and because of my limited knowledge, I'm unable to debug. :-( the login-box still appears, even if I call `domain.abc/index.php?s=abc`

Comment: Hm, does it work if you use `^/index.php$` instead of `^index.php$`?